# Viewmodel shows wrong information and how pass a warning

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a register form. On the submit I check if the emailaddress is already registred in the database. If this is the case I redirect to the registerform again with an empty emailaddress.

The form is filled in but the emailaddress is still the one that the user filled in on the first time. How is this possible? Here is some of my code

### Razor page

```
@model LibModels.User
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>

        <div class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userEmail)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userEmail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userEmail)
        </div>    <p>
            <input id="knop" type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]


public ActionResult Register(User viewModel)
    {
        User usr = Adapter.UserRepository.Single(u => u.userEmail.Equals(viewModel.userEmail));
        if (usr == null)
        {
            viewModel.userCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            Adapter.UserRepository.Insert(viewModel);
            Adapter.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            viewModel.userEmail = "";
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

It would also be nice to have a warning in the validation that this emailaddress already exists in the database, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is

```
ModelState.AddModelError("userEmail", "Email already exists");
```

However, I'd suggest looking into creating a custom action filter to do the validation for you.  It's a lot cleaner & easy to test.

Here's a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation.aspx).

Comment: Yes that helped for the error part. But the most important part is that the emailfield should be empty. Because I changed the modelview to: viewModel.userEmail = ""; Why is it still displaying the emailaddress that was entered by the user?

Comment: hmmm ... I don't know.  Is that your exact code?  Have you stepped through it to confirm it's doing what you think?  If so, then maybe turn on 'Enable .NET Framework source stepping' and see where's it's getting lost.

Comment: 'Enable .NET Framework source stepping? Where to be found? I have debugged the loop and my modelview.userEmail is empty when I return the view...

Comment: Tools | Options | Debugging | General | Enable .NET Framework source stepping ... you may have to download the symbols as well, Tools | Options | Debugging | Symbols